# Using Hibernate or alternative with PostgreSQL on Android 4.0+

Tags: java, android, hibernate, dalvik

I need to use the database layer between Java code and Database without pain on both platforms PC and Android. I would be very happy to stick with Hibernate if possible as I have PC application where database is connected by using Hibernate and there are many annotation inside my classes. Now I need to create Android application that would connect to the same database and the best option would be to reuse the same hibernate entities-code as on PC.

- from what i know Hibernate is not supported on Android, does anyone made it working?
- is there any alternative to Hibernate on Android (db: PostgreSQL) that would support loading/saving complex entities/tables including nested @OneToMany @ManyToMany relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses bytecode manipulation under the hood -  and this is not available on android at runtime.  Better solution would be to let hibernate live on your server,  and wrap your API in webservices